# Does "make offline" option in Google Maps works with applications that utilize Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, offline-map

In newer Google Maps I can make area available offline.

Do other applications that rely on Google Maps (utilize Google Maps Android API) use offline maps?

Answer (score 1):

No.
I have made my current city offline. But, when I do local search with third-party apps, the map is displayed after consuming internet connection.

Its task of third-party apps to cache fetched map data for future use.

Comment: Sure? What about the Maps API? And as for search: That may be a separate thing (as is route calculation) which may require a server connection. If a 3rd party app simply wants to display a map area: couldn't it request so via the API, and it would be delivered from cache?

Comment: @Izzy Google Maps also uses API. Its not a part of it. Its possible that An Android device may NOT have Google Maps app.

Comment: Sure, I know that (have a couple of those without maps). But the API is built into the system. So my *question* was rather whether caching (and cache access) is/can-be handled via the API. If so, this must be possible by 3rd-party apps as well -- which of course does not mean it's *implemented* with all of them.

Comment: @Izzy The question asks different thing. It doesn't ask, an app can access cache or not. It asks: If one makes an area offline in Google Maps app, would it be offline for all apps?

Comment: OK, tnx anyway. If you take it that literally, the answer of course is a short "No".

Comment: @Izzy caching is implanted in the clients not in the api.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik Thanx -- short and precise answer!